# Difference between convert Imagemagik utility and python PIL convert

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, python-imaging-library

I used the convert Imagemagik utility to create the grayscale jpg images. Need help in finding  the equivalent utility in Python. I tried PIL but this create png images. 
I thought of calling the "convert" utility through python. Is there any better solution than this.
I want to feed the images in tensorflow. The issue is I am using tensorflow 1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh? This works fine and creates a grey JPEG:

```
from PIL import Image
image=Image.open('start.png')
grey=image.convert('L')
grey.save("result.jpg")
```